# set xticks label frequency with python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to reduce the frequency of x tick marks. The x values are date :

```
date=['20120101','20120101','20120101',...'20121231']
```

I have 24 time steps for each day of the year. And I would like to label the xticks each 24 time steps (i.e., each day).

Here is the code that I use:

```
date=[]
val=[]
for lig in file(liste.txt):
   ligne=lig.split('')
   date.append(ligne[0])
   val.append(ligne[1])

plt.plot(date,val)
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation=90)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y%m%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=4))
plt.show()
```

And here is my plot, there are no xticks label !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no *complete* and working example, we have to guess: Is your `date` properly recognized as datetime object? If not, the `set_major_locator` in the date-format would result in no x-ticks.

You can achieve this using something like `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')`.

Comment: I'd add that the documentation clearly specifies that the format string has to comply with [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: I have completed my example. When I add date=datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%y%m%d'), it returns        descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'list'

Comment: First of all, that's not what I call a working example. There are two typos: `plt.gca().xaxix.(...)` and `dateFormatter('%y%m%d')`, both resulting in an `Attribute error`. Secondly, it seems like you have to treat every element separately, as e.g. creating a second empty list `date2=[]` and then fill it with `for itm in date: date2.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(itm, '%Y%m%d'))
`. You have to plot `date2` instead of `date` then, which btw is an unfortunate name for a variable. (I'm sure, there is a more pythonic way to write this! I'm not experienced with lambda functions.)